# sorting array by predefined number

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have multidimensional array

```
var arr = [{
    "id": "1",
    "firstname": "SUSAN",
    "dezibel": "91"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "firstname": "JOHNNY",
    "dezibel": "74"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "firstname": "ANDREA",
    "dezibel": "67"
}];
```

How can I sort it by "dezibel" but not ascending or descending, but closest to a giving number? For example,

```
var num = 78;
```

so target value is 78. and final sorting must be: 74, 67, 91.

Comment: but dezibel is logarithmic value, maybe the sorting should respect that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) optionally takes a function. The function takes 2 values at a time, and compares them:

- If the first value should sort higher than the second, the function should return a positive number.
- If the first value should sort lower than the second, the function should return a negative number.
- If the values are equal, the function should returns `0`.

So, if you wanted to sort by `dezibel` in ascending order, you could do

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.dezibel- b.dezibel;
});
```

However, you want to sort by `dezibel`'s distance from some number. To find the magnitude of the difference from `78` and the `dezibel` value, take the absolute value of the difference:

```
Math.abs(78 - a.dezibel)
```

Now, if we want to sort based on that value for each object, we can take the difference of that `Math.abs` call for both `a` and `b`:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return Math.abs(78 - a.dezibel) - Math.abs(78 - b.dezibel);
});
```

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I will accept this as an answer because it's the most detailed response.

Answer (score 2):

Write a sort function which calculates the distance to your number:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b){
    return Math.abs(num-a) - Math.abs(num-b);
});
```

Use this to sort the `dezibel` properties in your array. It will calculate the distance between each of them and `num`. It will then select the smaller of the two distances, and continue in this manner to sort the whole array.

Comment: This will need to access the properties of the objects in the array, not just the array elements.

Comment: I was simply showing the sort function, I will edit my text to be more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a custom sort function that compares the absolute difference of each object's `dezibel` attribute from 78.

```js
var arr = [{
    "id": "1",
    "firstname": "SUSAN",
    "dezibel": "91"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "firstname": "JOHNNY",
    "dezibel": "74"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "firstname": "ANDREA",
    "dezibel": "67"
}];

num = 78;

arr.sort(
  function(first,second){
    var a = Math.abs(num - (+first.dezibel));
    var b = Math.abs(num - (+second.dezibel));
    return a - b;
  });

alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just sort by the absolute difference.

```js
var arr = [{ "id": "1", "firstname": "SUSAN", "dezibel": "91" }, { "id": "2", "firstname": "JOHNNY", "dezibel": "74" }, { "id": "3", "firstname": "ANDREA", "dezibel": "67" }],
    num = 78;

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a.dezibel - num) - Math.abs(b.dezibel - num);
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array sort function for this:

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
   return num - 1 * a.dezibel + num - 1 * b.dezibel
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a distance and then sort it ...

```
num=78
for e in arr
    e.dist=Math.abs(e.dezibel - num)
arr.sort (l,r) =>
    if l.dist > r.dist then 1 else -1
```

delete the dist after

but put in one line is ok,  too

```
    arr.sort (l,r) =>
        if Math.abs(l.dezibel - num) > Math.abs(r.dezibel - num) then 1 else -1
```